# Loop don't go throught the dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I'm trying to convert all the column of my dataframe to the date format, their class is currently chr.

My code is working without the loop (when I specify the column: df$colname)

```
df_2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(df)))

for (i in colnames(df)){
  var <- data.frame(as.POSIXct(df$i, format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  df_2 <- cbind(df_2, var)
}
```

My dataframe (df):

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-02 09:43:45 | 2015-01-05 10:08:48 |
| 2015-01-02 10:15:44 | 2015-01-05 10:21:05 |

```
col1<- c("2015-01-02 09:43:45   ", "2015-01-02 10:15:44")
col2 <- c("2015-01-05 10:08:48","2015-01-05 10:21:05")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Use `df[[i]]`, not `df$i`.

Comment: It still not working in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create df2 with the same structure of df:

```
df_2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(df),ncol=ncol(df)))
```

Then, the loop should run in a sequence. In your case is the number of columns. Then you want to add the formatted data as date, to df2, according with the number of columns. So, the loop should work like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df_2[i]<-as.POSIXct(df[,i],format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  colnames(df_2)<-names(df)
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Just need to add ``` origin='1970-01-01'``` and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using loops at all, if you want to.  Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
       col1=c("2015-01-02 09:43:45", "2015-01-05 10:08:48"),
       col2=c("2015-01-02 10:15:44", "2015-01-05 10:21:05")
     )

d %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.POSIXct(., format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  col1                col2               
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2015-01-02 09:43:45 2015-01-02 10:15:44
2 2015-01-05 10:08:48 2015-01-05 10:21:05
```

I am unable to reproduce OP's issue with my solution.  I've provided the output I obtain above.

It might possibly be a version issue. The versions of the packages I am using are given below:

```
> packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.3.1’
> packageVersion("tibble")
[1] ‘3.1.5’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.7’
> packageVersion("base")
[1] ‘4.1.0’
```

Beyond that, I have no suggestions.

Also, please bear in mind that it is not good practice to upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Thanks ! it's a more efficient way

Comment: Your solution go through all my dataframe but my raws are still chr after it.

Comment: I don't see how that could be - as you will see from my example, all columns are date times, as demonstrated by the `<dttm>`s in the output.  Please edit your question to include a full demonstration of the problem: input data, the code you used and the output.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: I will check packages, in any case thank you for your time !